# Wordpress for business site

Tags: posts, pages

My domain is from one.com, that recently added a wordpress feature.But when i'm trying to use it it converts my website in a blog. So, I want to do my website with Wordpress but without posts from my page and just do convencional business page. Anyone know how can i do that?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by "converts your website" exactly? Without context on your existing setup and your host's features it is hard to follow what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new page from the wordpress menu, then go to settings->reading->a static page and choose the page you just created: this page will be the main page when you visit the website.